# What kind of SQL join would this be?

Tags: sql, expressionengine

I need to go to two tables to get the appropriate info

```
exp_member_groups
-group_id
-group_title

exp_members
-member_id
-group_id
```

I have the appropriate member_id

So I need to check the members table, get the group_id, then go to the groups table and match up the group_id and get the group_title from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT exp_member_groups.group_title
FROM exp_members
INNER JOIN exp_member_groups ON exp_members.group_id = exp_member_groups.group_id
WHERE exp_members.member_id = @memberId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT g.group_title
FROM exp_members m
    JOIN exp_member_groups g ON m.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE m.member_id = @YourMemberId
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is always a matching group, or you only want rows where it is, then it would be an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT  g.group_title
FROM    exp_members m
        INNER JOIN
                exp_member_groups g
                ON m.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE   m.member_id = @member_id
```

If you want rows even where group_id doesn't match, then it is a `LEFT JOIN` - replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` in the above.